# I want to check the given matrix by user is identity matrix or not

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class twoD
{

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner Scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int[][] mat = new int[3][3];    //getting input from user in 2d array   
        System.out.println("enter the rows and columns");

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                mat[i][j] = Scan.nextInt();
            }
        }       //printing the array    

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
            {
                System.out.print(mat[i][j] + " ");
            }

            System.out.println();
        }

        if ((mat[0][0]) == (mat[1][1]) == (mat[2][2]) && 
                (mat[0][1]) == (mat[0][2]) == (mat[1][0]) == (mat[1][2]) == (mat[2][0]) == (mat[2][1]))
        {
            System.out.println("IT is a elementary matrix");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("NOT!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please indent your code

Comment: You can't chain comparisons like that. Also, you're not checking whether the diagonal entries are 1 or the non-diagonal entries are 0, only whether they're equal to each other.

Answer (score 1):

you cannot compare more than 2 variables at a time following.

```
a == b == c
```

instead of this you need to compare like following

```
(a == b) && (b == c)
```

also accorind to the definition of [identity matrix](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_matrix)

> identity matrix or unit matrix of size n is the n × n square matrix with ones on the main diagonal and zeros elsewhere

so your concept is also wrong .. just check if the diagonal values are 1 and others are 0.

Answer (score 0):

For checking Identity Matrix, first check whether it's **rows and columns are same or not**.

And check the sequence

### 0,(n+1),2(n+1),3(n+1),..,n(n+1) positions

of Matrix should be **ONE**
and others should be **ZERO**